# Juniper Netscreen email alert SSG-550M

Tags: juniper, netscreen

I'm having some problems configuring email alerts on Netscreen 6.3r22 on 2 SSG-550M in an NSRP group active/active. I'm aware that there are limitations of sending SMTP alerts via mail servers requiring authentication however mails don't appear to be generating from the Firewall at all

When I turn on debugging and check

```
debug sendmail all
get db stream
```

I get this output which is confusing

```
## 2016-08-23 16:37:50 : Notify (1)
## 2016-08-23 16:37:50 : Prepare to send mail [sort=0]
## 2016-08-23 16:37:50 : Mail server name : mail.example.com
## 2016-08-23 16:37:50 : begin to send event alarm, start time=78611, current time=79211, max entries=102
## 2016-08-23 16:37:50 : total event alarm record 2 retrieved, start_time=78611
## 2016-08-23 16:37:50 : fail to send no 0 due to (log time[78878] < last_sent_event_time [79211] && allowed to email [0])
## 2016-08-23 16:37:50 : fail to send no 1 due to (log time[78857] < last_sent_event_time [79211] && allowed to email [0])
## 2016-08-23 16:37:50 : last event id = -1
## 2016-08-23 16:37:50 : Event alarm: Log entries sent out=0, Last Log entry id=-1, time=79211
```

I've configured a mail server and admin addresses

```
Mail Alert: On, Mail Server: mail.example.com
E-Mail Address: me@example.com
E-Mail Traffic Log: Off
Configuration Format: DOS
Device Reset: Enabled
Hardware Reset: Enabled
Admin privilege: read-only (Remote admin has read-only privileges)
Max Failed Admin login attempts: 10
Lock admin accounts on auth failure: On, locking time 1 minutes
HTTP redirect: true
```

I dont see anything hitting the mail server but I can't seem to find an explanation of those failure types on Juniper forums. from this output, to me it looks as though the mails don't send  but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the WebUI, navigate under `Configuration -> Report Settings -> Log Setting` and be sure to check all flags for the `Email` row.

Comment: Should have seen that. Thanks

mails arriving now. Just for reference this is what the mails look like from the debug once set for alerts. Mine were only set for critical events.

## 2016-08-24 09:28:24 : num event alarm alerts for e-mail = 3
## 2016-08-24 09:28:31 : num event alarm alerts for e-mail = 4
## 2016-08-24 09:28:42 : num event alarm alerts for e-mail = 5
## 2016-08-24 09:28:56 : num event alarm alerts for e-mail = 6